# Reshaping Pandas Dataframe for Mail Merge in Word

Tags: python, pandas, ms-word, mailmerge

I've a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Customer ID     Invoice ID  Invoice Total   Customer Total
8063863         110100456        41,47         248,82
8063863         110100677        41,47         248,82
8063863         110100838        41,47         248,82
8063863         110101106        41,47         248,82
8063863         110101259        41,47         248,82
8063863         110101401        41,47         248,82
```

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
Customer ID  Invoice_1    Invoice_Total_1    Invoice_2    Invoice_Total_2 ... Customer_Total
8063863      110100456              41,47    110100677              41,47         248,82
```

I'd like to then export the Dataframe to csv and use it in Word to Mail Merge the different clients their summary.

I added the Customer Total in Pandas using pivot_table but I'm stuck on the flattening of the Dataframe.

Comment: Hope this link can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641615/concatenate-multiple-rows-to-one-single-row-in-pandas

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that out. Melt and stack to frame should do the trick somehow. I'll see if I can get this to work with a single unique customer ID and then multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
def f(x):
    n,i = pd.factorize(x['Invoice ID'])
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.loc[(x['Invoice ID']==i.values),'Invoice Total'].values], columns=(n+1).astype(str)).add_prefix('Invoice_Total_')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([i.values],columns=(n+1).astype(str)).add_prefix('Invoice_')
    return pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).assign(Customer_Total=x['Customer Total'].max()),drop=True)

df_out = df.groupby('Customer ID').apply(f).reset_index(-1,drop=True)
```

Output:

```
            Invoice_Total_1 Invoice_Total_2 Invoice_Total_3 Invoice_Total_4  \
Customer ID                                                                   
8063863               41,47           41,47           41,47           41,47   

            Invoice_Total_5 Invoice_Total_6  Invoice_1  Invoice_2  Invoice_3  \
Customer ID                                                                    
8063863               41,47           41,47  110100456  110100677  110100838   

             Invoice_4  Invoice_5  Invoice_6 Customer_Total  
Customer ID                                                  
8063863      110101106  110101259  110101401         248,82
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works beautifully. I've to really step up my understanding of pandas